# Elastic Error: 500 - all shards failed

Tags: r, elasticsearch

I try to execute the following statement in R

```
elastic::Search("indexname", search_type = "scan")
```

and get the following error message

> Error: 500 - all shards failed

Everything works if I use

```
elastic::Search("indexname")
```

Does anybody know what I have to do? I remember a similar error when I used ES v5

I'm using ES v2.4.3.

Comment: try setting `connect(errors = "complete")` to get more verbose errors, you should get the elasticsearch trace stack back

Comment: I execute `elastic::Search(es_idx, scroll = "3m", search_type = "scan")` and then I get `Error: 500 - all shards failed
    ES stack trace:

    type: exception
    reason: Scroll must be provided when scanning...`

Comment: It just dont work on R studio server. Thats weird. On my local computer and in terminal it works.

Comment: The error message gives you the reason: `Scroll must be provided when scanning`

Comment: Yes, but I execute `elastic::Search(es_idx, scroll = "3m", search_type = "scan")`. It works local and in terminal but not on shiny server or R studio server :/